# How to gather DTMF tones on a two way call with Twilio programmable voice

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I am currently using the Twilio Client SDK for Android to make a call from Person A's android app (built by me) to Person B's phone. I am trying to figure out how Person A's android app can listen to DTMF tones passed in by Person B's dialpad and provide feedback based on the input. Right now it seems like the Twilio Client SDK for programmable voice does not support this use case.

One of the ideas that has been presented can be found here: [How to gather Twilio DTMF input from call recipient on outbound call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809214/how-to-gather-twilio-dtmf-input-from-call-recipient-on-outbound-call/53809964). However, I don't want Person B to have to be disconnected from the call. I also am not sure if I can set up a conference call and then initiate a call to Person B.

Another idea that has been presented is allowing a third party server to join this conference, and process the DTMF tones. Based on the input the server could send a push notification to Person A's app.

I'm not sure what the ideal solution is here and what is feasible. I'd like to start a conference between A and B and have my separate server listen in on the conference. But again, I'm not sure if this is valid.